# SQL how to select distinct several columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

lets say there are several columns (c1, c2, c3, c4)
It's okay for each column to be appeared several times,
but I want to select all the columns with several columns distinct.

I want `SELECT c1, DISTINCT(c2, c3), c4` something like this
but it doesnt work, and GROUP BY doesnt work as well.

somebody help me please

Comment: What should be the desired recordset if c2 or c3 has a different value in each row?
Lets say on first row c2='A' and c3=1 and in second row c2='A' and c3='2' than how can you get distinct record?
you can find multiple distinct clauses answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42505531/multiple-distinct-on-clauses-in-postgresql

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect results?

Comment: `distinct` is not a function. It is required to follow the SELECT keyword and always applies to all columns in the SELECT list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply can use `distrinct on`

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (c2, c3) *
FROM YOURTABLENAME
```

Comment: You also need an `ORDER BY`